# How to properly restart a MySQL Master server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, master-slave-replication

We are running on Azure VM wherein you can not expand the attached disk while the VM is running. So we need to stop the VM first before doing anything on the disk size/performance.

We just have 1 slave server for this replication.

I've read some procedures online in doing this, please confirm if this is appropriate.

**On Slave Server**

```
STOP SLAVE;
```

**On Master Server**

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Once stopped, update the VM settings (expand disk). Then start the VM.

**On Slave Server**

```
START SLAVE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stop the slave. It will continue once the master restarts. It tries every 60 second or so to connect.

Only stopping the master service/vm is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the input! :D